# Extending dplyr and use of internal functions

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, r-s3

I'm working on a fork of the `RSQLServer` package and am trying to implement joins. With the current version of the package, joins for any DBI-connected database are implemented using `sql_join.DBIConnection`. However, that implementation doesn't work well for SQL server. For instance, it makes use of `USING` which is not supported by SQL server.

I've got a version of this function `sql_join.SQLServerConnection` working (though not complete yet). I've based my function on `sql_join.DBIConnection` as much as possible. One issue I've had is that `sql_join.DBIConnection` calls a number of non-exported functions within `dplyr` such as `common_by`. For now, I've worked around this by using `dplyr:::common_by`, but I'm aware that that's not ideal practice.

Should I:

1. Ask Hadley Wickham/Romain Francois to export the relevant functions to make life easier for people developing packages that build on `dplyr`?
2. Copy the internal functions into the package I'm working on?
3. Continue to use the `:::` operator to call the functions?
4. Something else?

Clearly with option 3, there's a chance that the interface will change (since they're not exported functions) and that the package would break in the longer term.

Sample code:

```
sql_join.SQLServerConnection <- function (con, x, y, type = "inner", by = NULL, ...) {
  join <- switch(type, left = sql("LEFT"), inner = sql("INNER"), 
                 right = sql("RIGHT"), full = sql("FULL"), stop("Unknown join type:", 
                                                                type, call. = FALSE))
  by <- dplyr:::common_by(by, x, y)
  using <- FALSE # all(by$x == by$y)
  x_names <- dplyr:::auto_names(x$select)
  y_names <- dplyr:::auto_names(y$select)
# more code
}
```

Comment: @hadley this could be a nice side-note / case study in your [R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) best practices section.

Comment: @NickK, Just a side comment: I had a similar problem with Google BigQuery and  implemented `sql_join` with `:::`. Please take a look at this [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery/pull/56). My guess is there is a very high probability that it should work with SQL Server right out of the box.

Comment: @NickK, also on topic: see [this discussion](https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery/pull/55) in the (already merged) pull request. I was explicitly encouraged to re-use the `dplyr` function with `:::` instead of re-implementing it.

Comment: @akhmed thanks. Looks like you faced similar issues to the SQL Server ones and had similar solutions! I'll try it and see.

Comment: That's great if it ends up being useful outside BigQuery too! (I guess the only change is: "JOIN EACH" will need to be replaced back to "JOIN" for SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you may not have to use those functions verbs. Since `dplyr` now put it's database functionality in `dbplyr`, the relevant code is [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/c8d60a634d07fa6972345407de459f76db64cf91/R/sql-generic.R#L47). I don't see the use of `auto_names` or `common_by` there.

I strongly recommend following the steps in [Creating New Backends](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/new-backend.html) after reading [SQL Translation](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html).

It may also be worth reviewing some other alternative backends, such as Hrbrmaster's [sergeant package](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/sergeant) for Apache Drill using JDBC.